# Coredata Migration Crash

Tags: ios, core-data, core-data-migration

In my latest app update I have a few users complaining about crashes and I managed to get my hands on a crash report. Here's the crash reason from the symbolicated crash log.

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: Namespace SPRINGBOARD, Code 0x8badf00d
Triggered by Thread:  0
```

This happens when I call `[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error:]`

Here's the complete stacktrace:

```
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: SQLQueue 0x12fecca10 for .database.db.migrationdestination_41b5a6b5c6e848c462a8480cd24caef3
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180640164 __fcntl + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180625660 fcntl + 84
2   libsqlite3.dylib                0x0000000181ba3f90 0x181b3d000 + 421776
3   libsqlite3.dylib                0x0000000181bb9e50 0x181b3d000 + 511568
4   libsqlite3.dylib                0x0000000181bcdf34 0x181b3d000 + 593716
5   libsqlite3.dylib                0x0000000181bcdd98 sqlite3_wal_checkpoint_v2 + 492
6   libsqlite3.dylib                0x0000000181ba41b0 0x181b3d000 + 422320
7   libsqlite3.dylib                0x0000000181b7b288 sqlite3_step + 976
8   CoreData                        0x000000018391b194 _execute + 164
9   CoreData                        0x000000018394ffd8 -[NSSQLiteConnection commitTransaction] + 312
10  CoreData                        0x0000000183a6ced8 __43-[_NSSQLiteStoreMigrator performMigration:]_block_invoke + 2784
11  CoreData                        0x0000000183a36cbc __37-[NSSQLiteConnection performAndWait:]_block_invoke + 40
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001804fe9a0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018050bee0 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 84
14  CoreData                        0x0000000183a36c08 -[NSSQLiteConnection performAndWait:] + 144
15  CoreData                        0x0000000183a6c35c -[_NSSQLiteStoreMigrator performMigration:] + 184
16  CoreData                        0x0000000183a63db0 -[NSSQLiteInPlaceMigrationManager migrateStoreFromURL:type:options:withMappingModel:toDestinationURL:destinationType:destinationOptions:error:] + 1912
17  CoreData                        0x00000001839ee814 -[NSMigrationManager migrateStoreFromURL:type:options:withMappingModel:toDestinationURL:destinationType:destinationOptions:error:] + 556
18  CoreData                        0x0000000183a5f090 -[NSStoreMigrationPolicy(InternalMethods) migrateStoreAtURL:toURL:storeType:options:withManager:error:] + 324
19  CoreData                        0x0000000183a5e3ec -[NSStoreMigrationPolicy migrateStoreAtURL:withManager:metadata:options:error:] + 120
20  CoreData                        0x0000000183a5fb08 -[NSStoreMigrationPolicy(InternalMethods) _gatherDataAndPerformMigration:] + 2440
21  CoreData                        0x00000001839fc188 __91-[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error:]_block_invoke + 4160
22  CoreData                        0x0000000183a08630 gutsOfBlockToNSPersistentStoreCoordinatorPerform + 168
23  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001804fe9a0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
24  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018050bee0 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 84
25  CoreData                        0x00000001839f7d70 _perform + 200
26  CoreData                        0x000000018390d5e4 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error:] + 388
```

I don't have more details on the crash. Only that it happens for a few users and not all. I have no idea how to reproduce it for a proper fix. The user reported that the app started, was "frozen" for some time and then it crashed. And it keeps doing so.

I had a look at the last version of the core-data model since I shipped the app and this file is still the exact same. During development I added 5 more versions in-between but that shouldn't be a problem right? The version shipped in the app before the update is untouched...

**EDIT:** The changes I made to the model were simply adding some new properties on existing entities. But if auto-migration would fail, it would fail for everybody, right? Not only for a few users?!?

So I was hoping somebody here already might had the same issue and a solution on how to fix it. Or at least a way on how to detect the problem without the app crashing. Then I could just recreate the DB for those users...

Comment: That's an interesting stack trace. Core Data starts off migration but then blows up at some point. I'd ask the user if their device is out of space. Also, it might be useful to edit your question to describe the changes you made to your model.

Comment: Hey Tom, I'll ask the user! What makes you think it could be low disc-space? I updated my question about the changes... The changes I made to the model were simply adding some new properties on existing entities. But if auto-migration would fail, it would fail for everybody, right? Not only for a few users?!?
Do you have any idea on how I might be able to reproduce the error?

Comment: Since it works for most users, it looks like you have migration set up correctly. Your stack trace supports that-- everything's running, but then **boom**. That leaves the question of what's unique about these few users. Running out of space wouldn't affect most users and could blow things up in the middle of an otherwise-working migration.

Comment: I just saw that doing the migration on my iPhone 7 takes about 1.5 seconds. Might it be a problem when a device is slower that it takes too long and springboard is therefore closing my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core-data migrations can take time.  If it takes too long for your first view to load then the watchdog will kick in a kill your app.  This can happen when you user has much more data than you expect. Instead add a migration checker.  And if you need to do a migration then show a loading UI with a loading animation while you load the store.

```
-(BOOL) storeNeedsMigrationAtURL:(NSString*) sourceStorePath{
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:sourceStorePath]) {
        // Database doesn't yet exist. No need to test data compatibility"
        return NO;
    }
    NSManagedObjectModel *model = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:"<Your models directory name>" ];
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:model];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSURL *sourceStoreURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:sourceStorePath];
    NSDictionary *sourceStoreMetadata = [NSPersistentStoreCoordinator metadataForPersistentStoreOfType:NSSQLiteStoreType URL:sourceStoreURL options:nil error:&error];

    // Do error checking... Removed from the code sample.
    NSManagedObjectModel *destinationModel = [psc managedObjectModel];
    BOOL isCompatible = [destinationModel isConfiguration:nil
                              compatibleWithStoreMetadata:sourceStoreMetadata];

    return isCompatible;
}
```

see https://vimeo.com/89370886 around 55 minutes 
you can also read
https://hamishrickerby.com/2012/06/04/core-data-migrations-and-large-data-sets/

Comment: Yep... indeed... in the meantime I made something like that! but the `isConfiguration:compatibleWithStoreMetadata` didn't detect it properly... instead I am now checking for entity hashes...
And if I detect a needed migration, I then present the user a waiting-dialog and to the migration in background...

And the problem why it only affected a few users it that it is fast if the database isn't that full, but once users have a lot of data, it takes much longer...